# Chartjs: Align pie chart to the left

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs

[image]

Im currently developing a Pie Chart with ChartJS (`3.9.1`) and `react-chartjs-2` wrapper,
my chart is using full-width.

I want my chart to stick to the left side, to be able to show more than 12 options. How can I stick the Pie Chart to the left? I've tried using `padding:0` already (ref. config).

My options config for the Pie Chart is:

```js
const optionsPie = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  layout: {
    padding: {
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
    },
  },
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'right' as const,
    },
  },
};
```